# jqTree getSelectNode Function

Tags: javascript, jqtree

I'm new to jqTree. I am trying to use the function: `getSelectedNode` found here:  [jqTree functions](http://mbraak.github.io/jqTree/#functions-getselectednode)   I have my tree working and being displayed using my own data as well as the sample data within this function:

```
 $(function() {
            $('#tree1').tree({
                data: data,
                dragAndDrop: true,
                autoOpen: 1
            });
        });
```

Using the jqTree function below, I only ever get "null" out on loading the page. Furthermore nothing changes when I select a node.

```
  var node = $('#tree1').tree('getSelectedNode');
  console.log(node);
```

I have also tried the given sample:

```
  var node = $tree.tree('getSelectedNode');
  console.log(node);
```

In this case I get `$tree not defined`

Essentially, what am I doing wrong? How does these type of jqTree functions work?   Tks !

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you have to wrap this function in a click event. But of course, the docs don't tell you that. I found the source here: [jqTree](http://cdn.skrepr.guru/cms/libs/jqtree/index.html#functions-loadData)  I htis helps someone else.

```
$('#tree1').bind(
'tree.click',
function(event) {
    // The clicked node is 'event.node'
    var node = event.node;
    alert(node.name);
}
```

);